# Creating default object from empty value in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla3

quiero traer las categorías que ya están registradas y los contactos lo cual no lo esta haciendo tengo el siguiente  código:

```
function listContacts( $option, $catid ) {
    global $mainframe, $database, $my;
    global $mosConfig_live_site;
    global $Itemid;

    /* Query to retrieve all categories that belong under the contacts section and that are published. */
    $query = "SELECT *, COUNT( a.id ) AS numlinks"
    . "\n FROM #__categories AS cc"
    . "\n LEFT JOIN #__contact_details AS a ON a.catid = cc.id"
    . "\n WHERE a.published = 1"
    . "\n AND cc.section = 'com_contact_details'"
    . "\n AND cc.published = 1"
    . "\n AND a.access <= " . (int) $my->gid
    . "\n AND cc.access <= " . (int) $my->gid
    . "\n GROUP BY cc.id"
    . "\n ORDER BY cc.ordering"
    ;

    $database->setQuery( $query );

    $categories = $database->loadObjectList();

    $count = count( $categories );

    if ( ( $count < 2 ) && ( @$categories[0]->numlinks == 1 ) ) {
        // if only one record exists loads that record, instead of displying category list
        contactpage( $option, 0 );
    } else {
        $rows       = array();
        $currentcat = NULL;

        // Parameters
        $menu = $mainframe->get( 'menu' );
        $params = new mosParameters( $menu->params );

        $params->def( 'page_title',         1 );
        $params->def( 'header',             $menu->name );
        $params->def( 'pageclass_sfx',      '' );
        $params->def( 'headings',           1 );
        $params->def( 'back_button',        $mainframe->getCfg( 'back_button' ) );
        $params->def( 'description_text',   _CONTACTS_DESC );
        $params->def( 'image',              -1 );
        $params->def( 'image_align',        'right' );
        $params->def( 'other_cat_section',  1 );
        // Category List Display control
        $params->def( 'other_cat',          1 );
        $params->def( 'cat_description',    1 );
        $params->def( 'cat_items',          1 );
        // Table Display control
        $params->def( 'headings',           1 );
        $params->def( 'position',           1 );
        $params->def( 'email',              0 );
        $params->def( 'phone',              1 );
        $params->def( 'fax',                1 );
        $params->def( 'telephone',          1 );

        if( $catid == 0 ) {
            $catid = $params->get( 'catid', 0 );
        }

        if ( $catid ) {
            $params->set( 'type', 'category' );
        } else {
            $params->set( 'type', 'section' );
        }

        if ( $catid ) {
            // url links info for category
            $query = "SELECT *"
            . "\n FROM #__contact_details"
            . "\n WHERE catid = " . (int) $catid
            . "\n AND published =1"
            . "\n AND access <= " . (int) $my->gid
            . "\n ORDER BY ordering"
            ;
            $database->setQuery( $query );
            $rows = $database->loadObjectList();

            // current category info
            $query = "SELECT id, name, description, image, image_position"
            . "\n FROM #__categories"
            . "\n WHERE id = " . (int) $catid
            . "\n AND published = 1"
            . "\n AND access <= " . (int) $my->gid
            ;
            $database->setQuery( $query );
            $database->loadObject( $currentcat );

            /*
            Check if the category is published or if access level allows access
            */
            if (!$currentcat->name) {
                mosNotAuth();
                return;
            }
        }

        // page description
        LINEA 147 $currentcat->descrip = '';
        if( isset($currentcat->description) && ($currentcat->description != '') ) {
            $currentcat->descrip = $currentcat->description;
        } else if ( !$catid ) {
            // show description
            if ( $params->get( 'description' ) ) {
                $currentcat->descrip = $params->get( 'description_text' );
            }
        }

        // page image
        $currentcat->img = '';
        $path = $mosConfig_live_site .'/images/stories/';
        if ( isset($currentcat->image) && ($currentcat->image != '') ) {
            $currentcat->img = $path . $currentcat->image;
            $currentcat->align = $currentcat->image_position;
        } else if ( !$catid ) {
            if ( $params->get( 'image' ) != -1 ) {
                $currentcat->img = $path . $params->get( 'image' );
                $currentcat->align = $params->get( 'image_align' );
            }
        }

        // page header
        $currentcat->header = '';
        if ( isset($currentcat->name) && ($currentcat->name != '') ) {
            $currentcat->header = $params->get( 'header' ) .' - '. $currentcat->name;
        } else {
            $currentcat->header = $params->get( 'header' );
        }

        // used to show table rows in alternating colours
        $tabclass = array( 'sectiontableentry1', 'sectiontableentry2' );

        HTML_contact::displaylist( $categories, $rows, $catid, $currentcat, $params, $tabclass );
    }
```

No identifico donde se encuentra el inconveniente link donde se ve el error 
http://www.ecoversa.org/index.php?option=com_contact&Itemid=3&lang=sp

Comment: ¿qué hay en la línea 147 de components/com_contact/contact.php ?

Comment: si mira la linea esta en el fragmento de código                                                                                                       // page description
        $currentcat->descrip = '';

Comment: Según ese error, lo más probable es que `$catid` no esté definido o que estés proporcionando un valor que no existe en dicha tabla.

Comment: mira al principio de la función esta definida la variable , y en la bases de datos esta por id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es sencillo de resolver, simplemente estás intentando asignar un valor a un elemento cuyo valor es `null`:

```
$currentcat = NULL;

...

$currentcat->descrip = '';
```

Debes definir primero el objeto de la clase correspondiente, antes de asignarle cualquier valor:

```
$currentcat = new \ObjetoClass(); // de la clase que sea

...

$currentcat->descrip = '';
```

Según la documentación de Joomla, el argumento que pasas a `loadObject` debe ser un string, el cual será el nombre de la clase que se utilizará para el objeto entregado:

> loadObject
>
> Method to get the first row of the result set from the database query as an object.
>
> loadObject(string $class = 'stdClass') : mixed

https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JDatabaseDriver.html#method_loadObject

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda